# Frame Rate drop Socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io, html5-canvas

I just started programming  with nodes.js and have an issue with my first example

Anybody can help me what the problem and how I maybe can check it by myself via console.log oft for example oft developer Tools in chrome.

My little script runs smoothly for about one minute and then the FPS drops slowly direction zero.
So I believe there is somewhere an overload within my code
On the Client side, I tried it with request Animation frame and with the setInternal same issue. Therefore i believe the problem is on the server side (and infront of the computer )

Here is an excerpt of my code

App.js

```
setInterval(function(){

var spliceArray = Array();
  objcnt = w.objects.length;
 var i=0;  
 while (i < objcnt)  
 {
 w.objects[i].update();
 if(w.objects[i].hitpoints <= 0 )
 spliceArray.push(i);           
 i++;
 }
 for(var k = 0;k<spliceArray.length;k++) 
 w.objects.splice(spliceArray[k],1);
 for(var i in SOCKET_LIST){
 var socket = SOCKET_LIST[i];
 //socket.emit('newClientship',allobjects[0]);
 socket.emit('newClientship',{x:allobjects[0].xtype.x,y:allobjects[0].xtype.y});
 }
},1000/25);
```

Index.html

```
setInterval(function(){
updateFps();
ctx.font="150px Arial"; 
ctx.fillStyle = "white"; 
socket.on('newClientship',function(data){
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.fillText(12,data.x,data.y);
 });
drawFps(200,20) ;
},1000/25);
```

What I tried is to create  objects on the Server side and Emit only the values for x and y to the client

Answer (score 0):

in `index.html`

```
setInterval(function(){
  …
  socket.on('newClientship',function(data){…
  …
},1000/25);
```

You are reassigning the event listener over and over again. Maybe that is the issue with `socket.io` Assign the listener just once, it will be called each time data arrives. If all your `updateFPS()` and canvas draw aren't the bottleneck, this should fix it.

Comment: Hey Philipp thanks can i ask you how i could get the listener into a set interval of request animation Loop on the Client? Should i listen for an array (via socket.on and outside Loops) and insert an array afterwards to the Main loop

Comment: Philipp thank you works great now! the fps text also stable now no more flickering . Strange that a Server can emit 25/s but a client cannot listen with 25/s but thats maybe due to i am a noobie. LOL.    Again thank you took me 3 nights headache and wanted give up already!